# Android app internationalization issue on tags with accentuation

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, internationalization

When we access the app menu and press our avatar/username, we go to the sites list. Further down we can see what we've been up to.

Questions are shown with tags in light gray. Those tags if containing accentuation appear with their HTML notation `&#number;` instead of the actual character:

[image: Screenshot]

---

Android APP version 1.0.15

**Model Number:** LG-P700
**Android Version:** 4.0.3
**Kernel version:** 3.0.8-perf (Wed Dec 12 20:18:47 KST 2012)

<sup>Any other information about the device, please feel free to ask.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in version 1.0.18, thanks!